# Update a primary key without triggering unique key violation

Tags: sql, sqlite

I just came to this very simple situation where I needed to shift a primary key up a certain value. Suppose the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
 Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 Desc TEXT);
```

Loaded with the following values:

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (0,'one');
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1,'two');
```

If there's an attempt at updating the primary key, it will, of course, fail:

```
UPDATE Test SET Id = Id+1;
```

> Error: column id is not unique

Is there some way to suspend unicity check until after the update query has run?

Comment: For those who would be curious, I made another table with the same columns but no primary key, transferred everything to it, shifted the value, flushed the original table, and reinserted everything back. I'm looking for something less... moronic?

Comment: And yes, shifting a primary key is suspicious, I agree. It was a time field that was off by a few hours. I know, I feel dirty.

Comment: OMG.  Are you using a time field as your primary key?  Definitely not a good idea.  Probably best to use an auto sequence integer as the PK, and keep the time in a separate field.  I suppose SQLLite doesn't take care of updating primary keys, many main-stream RDBMS will not have prob with your UPDATE query.  Nevertheless, it is an embedded database, so it may not have all the features of mainstream products.

Comment: @StephenChung: In my defense, the database is not my design. I'm just a victim.

Comment: @StephenChung: And in the real-life case, that key is a two-fielder...

Comment: OK. I remember from my *long* years ago DB class with Mike Stonebraker. He did mention that the RDBMS implementations at that time were not as sophisticated. He mentioned that in such a case of updating unique keys, if increment doesn't work, then try decrement.  That's because the database engine may be simply doing a table scan in order and just trying to update one row at a time.  If it is going up, then +1 won't work, but -1 may work.  See another potential answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find a nice pivot point, and move the data around that pivot. For example, if all your IDs are positive, a good pivot is 0.

When you would normally do

```
UPDATE Test SET Id = Id+1;
```

Do this sequence instead

```
UPDATE Test SET Id = -Id;
UPDATE Test SET Id = -Id +1;
```

For times, you can find a similar pivot point, but the formula is just a tad harder.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the last two statements would result in UPDATE Test SET Id = Id-1; and not in UPDATE Test SET Id = Id+1;

Answer (score 1):

without understanding the fundamental problem (and yeah, you seem like a victim of code and run on this one!), multiplying the ID by the largest value in the table should work.

```
update test
set id = id * (select max(id) + 1 from test)
```

However, it's dirty, and really, databases make it hard to change primary keys for a reason...

Comment: Cute trick! Doesn't apply to my real-life example, but it applies to the question as I laid it out. +1

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Second attempt.  Try this:

1. Get the MAX of the key column.
2. UPDATE table SET key = key + max + 1
3. UPDATE table SET key = key - max

This will avoid duplicated keys at any time in the update process by moving the window far enough.

Comment: Why does this not replace the other answer?

Comment: Well, the first answer was wrong, but there is some valuable info in it (i.e. SQLite can't drop a PK). Should I just attach this answer at the back?

Comment: I normally would, but your answer - your call